# Optimize Breadth First Search

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have been getting timeout errors for this particular graph theory [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/rust-murderer). I tried optimizing my code as much as I could but it's still not meeting the HackerRank performance standards for this problem. To give you a basic run down, I first assume a fully connected graph and run a BFS on it, avoiding the edges which are city roads. But instead of creating the actual graph for every test case, I made a generator which lets my BFS function iterate through only the nodes to which the current node is connected by a village edge. Any hint on how I can optimize it more would be appreciated.

```
from collections import deque
T = input()

# BFS
def return_nodes(N,a,edges):
    for i in xrange(1,N+1):
        if i != a and (i,a) not in edges and (a,i) not in edges:
            yield i

def bfs(start,N,edges):
    S,q,dist = set(),deque(),{}
    S.add(start)
    q.append(start)
    dist[start] = 0
    while q:
        current_node = q.popleft()
        for i in return_nodes(N,current_node,edges):
            if i in S: continue
            S.add(i)
            q.append(i)
            dist[i] = dist[current_node] + 1
    return dist

for i in xrange(T):
    N,M = map(int,raw_input().split())
    # Main roads/edges
    main_edges = set()
    for j in xrange(M):
        a,b = map(int,raw_input().split())
        main_edges.add((a,b))
    start = input()
    dist = bfs(start,N,main_edges)
    for k in dist:
        if k != start:
            print dist[k],
    print " "
```

Comment: Generate a complete graph on `N` vertices then remove the edges that are passed in the input (i.e. the town roads) which will leave a graph containing only the country roads - then run your BFS (or Dijkstra's algorithm without an end-point) on this sparse graph.

Comment: I did that before. It was taking O(N^2) time and I was getting even more timeout errors.

Comment: Maintain a set of unvisited vertices and a priority queue of vertices to visit (sorted by distance with, initially, only the start vertex at distance zero) then as each vertex is removed from the priority queue and visited remove it from that unvisited set and add only those remaining unvisited vertices (with incremented distance) to the priority queue which are not connected by a road.